# Retrieving capturing groups from Regex Matcher

Tags: java, regex

How would I parse the two numbers in the following string:

```
String fName = "Run_1_vs_2_pw_optimal_mapping.txt";
```

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    Pattern filePatt = Pattern.compile("Run_(\\d+)_vs_(\\d+)_", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher scanner = this.filePatt.matcher(fName);
    while (scanner.find()) {
            int groupSize = scanner.groupCount();
            if (groupSize == 2) {
                firstRun = Integer.parseInt(scanner.group(0));
                secondRun = Integer.parseInt(scanner.group(1));
            }
            break;
     }
```

However, this doesn't work, because scanner.group(0) returns `Run_1_vs_2`. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29).

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

Use `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the group number `0` corresponds to the full match. The captures are counted from `1`. What you want is captures `1` (first set of parentheses) and `2` (second set of parentheses).

Comment: @user1881788 please consider accepting one of our answers (preferably the other one!) to give the answerer some credit and show future visitors that (and how) your problem has been solved.